# How to bypass calls to the OwinStartup class for WEB API 2 requests that are part of ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using OpenId connect protocol for setting up the AzureAD authentication for ASP.NET MVC5 application. It is working fine as expected. The same code base has WEB API 2 controllers which is used by another angular app. The WEB API endpoints are setup with allow anonymous access in the root web.config file which is common for both ASP.NET MVC5 app and the WEB API 2 controllers.
There is a `Startup.cs` page which contains the logic for the OpenID connect protocol implementation.

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.CMS.Web.Startup))]

namespace MyApp.CMS.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

The namespace for the WEB API 2 Controllers is `MyApp.CMS.Web.Controllers.ApiControllers`

Here I want to stop execution of all the calls that are made to `Startup.cs` whenever any WEB API endpoint is invoked.

Can anyone help me to provide their guidance to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The WEB API endpoints are setup with allow anonymous access in the root `web.config` file

Actually, no - that is not possible.

Both MVC and Web API use HTTP modules as endpoints (that end up calling controller action methods). The ASP.NET `web.config` settings only apply to *physical files and folders* on the web server. MVC and Web API bypass these `web.config` settings so they have no effect.

> Here I want to stop execution of all the calls that are made to `Startup.cs` whenever any WEB API endpoint is invoked.

The code in `Startup.cs` is only executed **one time per application start** (or app pool refresh), so the only thing that takes place here are application-wide settings. It doesn't take part in the per-request authorization of controller actions.

---

If you want to control access to Web API controller action methods, you should use `[Authorize]` attribute from the `System.Web.Http` namespace (or a customized subclass of it). You will also need to [setup Authorization with Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) for `[Authorize]` attribute to function.

To apply authorization to the entire Web API, you can register `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` as a global filter.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
```

MVC has its own `[Authorze]` attribute and completely ignores the one from Web API, so this setting will have no effect on MVC.

Comment: I want to stop the execution of OWIN middleware pipleine in case a request comes for web api endpoint. Any other request should pass through the OWIN middleware pipeline.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible (or practical). Every example I have found uses OWIN middleware for *authentication*, but always uses `[Authorize]` attribute (or a subclass of it) for authorization. [Here is one such example](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/25/securing-asp-net-web-api-endpoints-using-owin-oauth-2-0-and-claims/).

Comment: In this case if any incoming request is coming in context of api endpoints then I need to end the execution there or else let it to proceed further execution.

Comment: That is what `[Authorize]` attribute does. And it can be registered globally (like in my answer) so it works on all Web API requests. Why reinvent the wheel? However, you still need to provide an authentication provider (which can be done through OWIN middleware as in the article I linked).

Comment: But here in this case the api code base is also part of the same assembly: MyApp.CMS.Web.Controllers.ApiControllers and hence the OwinStartup triggers for any api requests also. I need to stop that execution instead of taking the custom filter route.